# React: Is putting Actions that update Stores in the ComponentWillMount a bad idea?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, flux, reactjs-flux

Tools :Reactjs 0.14.0, React-Router 1.0.0, Vanilla Flux

So I have Action pushing to a store in my componentWillMount and it's now throwing the error:

**"Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invariant Violation: Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch"**

All my dispatching should of been done years before this call was made but
**finally I realized that my final emitChange() was not coming back until apparently all the re-rendering the emitChange() caused.**

For Example Code flows 1-4:

1)I change state in the InitStore that `InitComplete` is now true

**InitStore.js**

```
case ActionTypes.INIT_COMPLETE:
    _initComplete();
    InitilizationStore.emitChange();
    // Not getting past here till all re-rendering was done
    break;
```

2)Now that will trigger a change rendering

**app.js**

```
if(this.state.initComplete) {
    return (
        <Main />
    );
}else{ 
   return (<div className="main-container">Loading...</div>);
}
```

3)In a child component of `Main` there will be a call to save a param of the route in the `componentWillMount`

**Threadlist.js**

```
componentWillMount: function(){
    var { threadID } = this.props.params
    ThreadActionCreators.setCurrentThread(threadID);//Invariant!!!No!!
},
```

4)But it looks like InitStore has not still not come back from `emitChange()`!

**Question:
  So should I in general not be updating stores in the componentWillMount?**

Answer (score 1):

The "Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch" occurs when an action synchronously triggers another action. Actions are intended to be notifications of a change in data, with all resultant logic handled by the store with no need for subsequent further actions to be triggered, so an action triggering another action can suggest that you are doing something wrong.

However, in some cases, such as yours, it is reasonable to want to trigger a further action in response to the creation or updating of a new component. In these situations you can avoid the dispatch error by making the second action asynchronous. The easiest way to do this is by putting the second action inside a setTimeout:

```
componentWillMount: function(){
    var { threadID } = this.props.params
    window.setTimeout(
        function () {ThreadActionCreators.setCurrentThread(threadID);},
        0
    );
},
```

Alternatively, if you prefer, you can put the dispatch call inside setCurrentThread() in the timeout, either should work.

Comment: "so an action triggering another action can suggest that *you are doing something wrong*." --- to be fair: it's an artificial limitation and flux implementations are not obliged to follow it (since there is no real technical problem with it).

Comment: Can suggest. I agree that it isn't normally a problem, and it is frustrating to have to deal with, but I can see why it is worth at least flagging as a potential issue.

Comment: "it is worth at least flagging as a potential issue" --- that's right. But for some reason they decided "deny it" instead of warning :-) And the thing is that it's usually "good guys" that suffer from it since the "bad guys" will still work it around with `setTimeout` ;-)

Comment: It may be worth noting that this problem goes away if you wrap your dispatches in React's `batchedUpdates`; see [this page](http://fluxxor.com/guides/react.html#batched-updates) and [this test case](https://github.com/BinaryMuse/fluxxor/blob/aad8778ad40681dabc7273761269e8d1058540c6/test/unit/test_dispatch_interceptor.js#L132-L154) for examples.